# How can I access one Windows Forms control from another Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I create a window form `Form.cs`. It has some controls(label1, label2, button1, button1 etc.). I also create a new window form `New_Form.cs` under `Form.cs`. Now I want to access label1, label2, button1 in `New_Form.cs`. How can I do this?

Comment: This has been asked [over and over again](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+[winforms]+pass+values+to+another+form) on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to be offensive, but I think that using control from another form is not a good design.

In my oppinion it is not good to couple one class (in this question `form1`) to the *inner* implementation of another class (controls of `form2´. If you, for some reason, have to change the inner design (e.g. showing the data with a different control) of that class, you have to change the other class too. That makes coding (and of course error searching) quite difficult.

If there is a need to exchange data between two classes, I would prefer using publioc Properties for that. In the inner design you can attach them to a control, but then this "coupling" stays in the same class)

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be bad design, you can access properties in another Form by making them public and then accessing them like this:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
Form1.button1.Visible = false;
```

Also here is an msdn page pertaining to your question

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6525896%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: this will only let him access the properties of the window which are declared in that window itself. What if a window *Z* is created in some *X* form and you need to access it from *Y*

Comment: If you know how to do that by all means give a better answer :)

Comment: i have no idea that's why i asked you.....also i haven't worked with windows form but curious to know how can that be achieved. So, i asked you thinking you might know dat as well...

Comment: this is getting ot but if you have visual studio you can create a Windows Form Application from the new project menu

Answer (score 1):

You can access the required properties by setting them as public properties in your `Parent` form. Not sure as why you would want the button,  if you want some thing to be executed for the click then you should encapsulate the logic into separate methods and them make the call.

If you have fewer details to pass then make constructors for the new form which would accept those values

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm([label1], [label2])
```

or

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm([parent form reference]) // so you could access require components
```